# What is the pop order for set?

Tags: python, data-structures

As `set('ate')==set('aet')` is True, why the result comes like below?

```py
Input: list(set('ate'))
Output: ['e', 'a', 't']
Input: list(set('aet'))
Output: ['a', 't', 'e']
```

I want an explanations for how the output is produced. To me the element's order of output is random.

I have tried with

```py
x = set('ate')
x.pop()
# 'e'
x.pop()
# 'a'
x.pop()
# 't'
```

Same problem, the order makes me confused.

Comment: Yes, the order you get when converting a set to a list (or otherwise iterate over it) is undefined. Thus, whether your result is `True` or not is *also* undefined; you have no guarantee of correctness when you write software that makes assumptions about its output.

Comment: ...a given implementation Python is perfectly legal to store set members in a format that allows fast lookup but also results in in-order traversal. It's also perfectly legal to do something like the way very new Python 3.x releases handle efficient dict lookups maintaining order. Anything is legal, so code making assumptions (and relying on them for correctness) is buggy, full-stop.

Comment: That makes sense then, thank you so much @CharlesDuffy

Comment: The ordering in sets is arbitrary, not undefined. Meaning you will always see *some* ordering but there is no guarantee which.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered collections; lists are ordered. A set is equal to another set if it contains the same elements, regardless of order.

However, a list is an *ordered* collection. Lists are equal if and only if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Comment: The main thing this doesn't explain is that traversal order for a set is undefined -- not guaranteed to be sorted, not guaranteed to be identical to input order, but also not guaranteed *not* to be any of those things. Thus, the order one gets when converting from a set to a list is likewise undefined.